# Surrogate keys in fact-less fact tables

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

Why do you need surrogate keys in fact-less fact tables (or many to many dimensional relation tables)

Comment: SUrrogate keys representing the dims or surrogate keys of the fact tables themselves?

Answer (score 1):

Few circumstances when assigning a surrogate key to the rows in a fact table is beneficial:

1. Sometimes the business rules of the organization legitimately allow multiple identical rows to exist for a fact table. Normally as a designer, you try to avoid this at all costs by searching the source system for some kind of transaction time stamp to make the rows unique. But occasionally you are forced to accept this undesirable input. In these situations it will be necessary to create a surrogate key for the fact table to allow the identical rows to be loaded.
2. Certain ETL techniques for updating fact rows are only feasible if a surrogate key is assigned to the fact rows. Specifically, one technique for loading updates to fact rows is to insert the rows to be updated as new rows, then to delete the original rows as a second step as a single transaction. The advantages of this technique from an ETL perspective are improved load performance, improved recovery capability and improved audit capabilities. The surrogate key for the fact table rows is required as multiple identical primary keys will often exist for the old and new versions of the updated fact rows between the time of the insert of the updated row and the delete of the old row.
3. A similar ETL requirement is to determine exactly where a load job was suspended, either to resume loading or back put the job entirely. A sequentially assigned surrogate key makes this task straightforward.